# How to write a list into a txt file with each item in a line without "\n"

Tags: python

I want to write a list of textual items into a .txt file, where each time is written in a new line. 
I tried this:

```
items = ['First line', 'Second line' , 'third line']
with open(filepath, "x") as f:
    f.writelines(line+"\n" for line in items)
```

but when I read the file, it shows:

```
['First line\n', 'Second line\n', 'third line\n']
```

How can I write the lines without \n?
BTW, I tried this:

```
f.writelines(line for line in items)
```

but it wrote all of the three items in one line:

```
['First lineSecond line Third line']
```

Comment: instead of `f.writelines` use `f.write`

Comment: If you write the sentences without newlines, you may have a problem reading them back in: newlines are pretty standard as separator between lines.

Comment: Write() takes only a string not a list. so it's not useful to append a list of strings. Also, it appends the text to the last line in the file, not as a new line. You still you can for-loop it, but this is exactly what writelines() does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` means line break and is required to match your conditions `each time is written in a new line`.

Just use `strip()` on each line after you read the *.txt file.

```
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for l in lines:
   print(l.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was asking for.